# Python Global Not Behaving As Expected

Tags: python, global-variables, global

The following prints out "None" instead of "whatever". I don't understand why.

```
dirr = None

def method():
    global dirr # you have to declare that you'll use global variable 'dirr'
    dirr = "whatever"

print `dirr`
```

Comment: you have to call the `method` first before `print(dirr)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call 'method' one time.

```
dirr = None

def method():
    global dirr # you have to declare that you'll use global variable 'dirr'
    dirr = "whatever"

method()
print (dirr)
```

The result is:

```
whatever
```